# Proving an inequation about the distance in triangles

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, triangles

I could need some help with this, 
Write down a prove, that shows that the following inequation is true for all a, b, c ∈ R^n
d(a, b) ≤ d(a,c) + d(c,b)

I'm thankful for every input

Comment: That is a very basic theorem, so, in order to answer your question, knowing the context is very important (that is, the axioms and theorems that you can use to prove it). Are you asking from linear algebra, from calculus, from geometry?

Comment: I think this is the definition of metric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)

Comment: I'm asking from the standpoint of linear algebra

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $d$ is defined as $d(a,b)=\|a-b\|$, then you can prove this using the triangle inequality of the norm in $\Bbb{R}^n$ :
$$\begin{align}
d(a,b)=\|a-b\|&=\|(a-c)+(c-b)\| \\
&\leq \|a-c\|+\|c-b\| \\
&=d(a,c)+d(c,b).
\end{align}$$